# Java program throwing exception while executingbatch

Tags: java, jdbc

I am implementing an JAVA application which takes data from different URL's and store this data to a databse.Each table has it's own collections of URL's from which it receives the data. I am doing this by implementing a preparedstatement for each table, get data from the URL, bind data to preparestatement and adding data as a batch until all the URL's for a table are finished. And then doing executeBatch on the prepare statement. I do have some 6-8 tables and each table has some 200 rows. I am doing the same procedure for each table but after updating 3-4 tables my executeBacth is thrwoing an exception which says :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: SQL Exception : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
 Manager] Invalid string or buffer length   at
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1438)
    at
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1073)
    at
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.emulateExecuteBatch(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.jjva:2104)
    at
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatchUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1782)
    at
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeBatch(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:911)
    at FaoClient.CFaoTable.InsertFromPartialSource(CFaoTable.java:174)
```

I have tested the same program by changing the order of fetching the data for tables but it is always throwing exception after inserting data 4-5 tables. I feel that it is like some memory leak situation but as I know JAVA grabage collector will never let this situaion happen. I am very new to this JAVA world so I might be wrong. I am pasting the part of my code which uses java.sql.* for purpose of inserting the records.

```
  private boolean BindValueToStmt(PreparedStatement ps, int index, TableCol.ColType type, String ColVal) {
        if ((ps == null) || (ColVal == "")) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            switch (type) {
                case INTEGERT: {
                    ps.setInt(index, Integer.parseInt(ColVal));
                    return true;
                }
                case STRINGT: {
                    ps.setString(index, ColVal);
                    return true;
                }
                case REALT: {
                    ps.setFloat(index, Float.parseFloat(ColVal));
                    return true;
                }
                case DOUBLET: {
                    ps.setDouble(index, Double.parseDouble(ColVal));
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    ps.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.NULL);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException E) {
            System.out.println("Error in Setting the value of the col in table: " + Name + E);
            E.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }



   private String CreatePreparedInsertStatement() {
        StringBuilder insertStmt = new StringBuilder("insert into " + Name + "(");
        String val = " values (";
        for (int index = 0; index < Columns.size(); index++) {
            TableCol col = Columns.get(index);
            if (index != Columns.size() - 1) {
                String Stmt = col.GetColName() + ", ";
                insertStmt.append(Stmt);
                val += "?, ";
            } else {
                String Stmt = col.GetColName() + ")";
                insertStmt.append(Stmt);
                val += "?)";
            }
        }
        insertStmt.append(val);
        return insertStmt.toString();
    }
```

And below is the code which is actually inserting the data.

```
  private boolean InsertFromPartialSource(Connection conn, SAXReader reader) {
        try {
            if (conn == null || reader == null) {
                return false;
            }
           //Some Code not realted to java.sql

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String strPs= CreatePreparedInsertStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strPs);

            //Some Code not realted to java.sql

            for (int index = 0; index < Columns.size(); index++) {
                    TableCol col = Columns.get(index);
                    //Some Code not realted to java.sql
                    if (!BindValueToStmt(ps, index + 1, col.GetColType(), colVal)) {
                        ps.setNull(index + 1, TableCol.GetSqlColTypeFrmType(col.GetColType()));
                    }
                }
                rowCount++;
                System.out.println(rowCount + "rows has been extracted for table \" " + Name);
                ps.addBatch();

            }
            if (rowCount > 0) {
                int RecordsUpdated[] = ps.executeBatch();
            }
            conn.commit();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            ps.close();
            return true;
}
```

I have only pasted the part of the function InsertFromPartialSource which is relevant to database update for clarity. Can someonw please indicate what things going wrong here?

**The solution to above problem is:**
Change your MySql Connector or Driver to MySqlJDBC driver. It can be
found on below link:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: In the catch block of 'BindValueToStmt' you should really rethrow the SQL exception and not just catch it and return false...

Comment: Which line is CFaoTable.java:174?

Comment: @auselen 
int RecordsUpdated[] = ps.executeBatch();

Comment: Probably a bug somewhere under your app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187827/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-invalid-string-or-buffer-length-error

Comment: @auselen Any suggestion to find the bug..Actually this is the whole code which is doing updation. Or can u point in the code which step might be dangerous..

Comment: @Manish I mean bug might be *below* your app, in driver. If you want to chase, stop using batch mode, insert one by one, if it is a malformed string thing you'll get it easier and you'll know which data makes it cry.

Comment: @home : Just for knowledge, What wil rethrowing the exception do..

Comment: Consider switching to the real JDBC driver for your database (if there is one). The JdbcOdbc bridge is rather bad, specific JDBC drivers usually work better

Comment: @Manish: in case of SQL exception it does not make any sense to further process the corresponding row. Carefully look at your execution path - it does not make sense to proceed after the SQL exception occured (it might even be the root cause for the issue you describe in your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
The driver was actual problem. I changed it to JDBC and now it is perfectly working. I spent around 7-8 hrs on this issue and finally found that problem was in the external library.Just asking as you people have more experienced with this, does MySQL not know that there is some problem in it's ODBC driver?

Comment: It is hard to say where to problem is, it could also be in the ODBC bridge implementation: in that case MySQL has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider switching to the real JDBC driver for your database (if there is one). The JdbcOdbc bridge is rather bad, specific JDBC drivers usually work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try execute, not executeBatch, to avoid lame batch operation.

Comment: Hi, but when you are inserting a large number of records, executing the inesert query for each record will be very inefficient.