# Prepared statement only throws exception when not debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

I use this piece of code to insert some data into database:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:war_odbc");
PreparedStatement st =
   con.prepareStatement(
      "INSERT INTO Actors(FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES(?,?,?)" );
st.setString(1, "Robert");
st.setString(2, "de Niro");
st.setInt(3,45);
st.executeUpdate();     
con.close();
```

If I use debugger and step one line at a time, everything goes well. If I don't use it and just run the application, I get this exception:

```
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.buildTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.
I went to Administrative Tools, Data Sources(ODBC) and i successfully tested it.

Comment: Since when is `de Niro` an integer?

Comment: The true question is: "Why this code works in debug mode?"...

Comment: De Niro's De Niro, he can be whatever he likes

Comment: Any chance you are using a different java interpreter when debugging and when running it normally? I.e. IDE used to debug has its own JVM "included" and the system installed JVM is different? Can you launch the code directly from the IDE ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to stop using this class from `sun` package ([Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)). Also this driver is really old, it's a type 1 driver that convert JDBC calls in ODBC calls.

Now almost all DB vendors have implemented type 4 driver. This driver implementation converts JDBC calls directly into a vendor-specific database protocol.

Also according to this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) this bridge will be removed in JDK8 so it's bad idea to use it if you want a portable / adaptable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I installed sqljdbc4.jar from microsoft.com but i am getting hard time trying to make it work. I will ask another question regarding to the new issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `st.setInt(2, "de Niro");` with `st.setString(2, "de Niro");`

Comment: That is a problem, but according to the stacktrace the error already occurs on `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Comment: The problem occurs during the SQL statement preparation. It is just propagated upwards in the call stack.

Comment: @Kata The error occurs before statement preparation, inside `DriverManager.getConnection()`, the stacktrace is quite clear.

Comment: So, any tips? What should i try?

Answer (score 0):

Just few points regarding the code snippet provided.

1. st.setInt(2, "de Niro");
   Here you are setting "string" as second parameter of query but you have used setInt()   method and thats incorrect.
2. Is itsomething related to your OS . i mean are u using 64-bit widows OS and 32 bit connector. i am not sure about it though.

Check this link.
["[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187827/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-invalid-string-or-buffer-length-error)